# What is the name of the fallacy when someone conflates a motivation for one of the variables?

Tags: meaning

Some examples:

"An atheist killed someone. They killed them because they were an atheist."

"A man strangled his wife. He is clearly a misogynist."

As you can see, one variable has been extrapolated and used as the causality, whereas in reality there are hundreds of cross-pollinating motivating variables.

Comment: Conifold's answer to your previous question (https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/a/42952/5381) answers this question...

Comment: Then why aren't those upvotes close votes?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What fallacy infers motivation from mere description?](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/42946/what-fallacy-infers-motivation-from-mere-description)

Answer (score 1):

This is primarily a genetic fallacy: you are deciding that origin or position explains outcomes.  But then you are layering on the assumption that correlation implies causation.

C.S. Lewis suggested this use of a genetic fallacy to hide another simple fallacy was so common in use that it needed a name of its own.  He decided to call it [Bulverism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bulverism).